# Keep state of menu open when clicked inside box

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, wordpress

I've created my own dropdown in Wordpress with a filter inside of it. When I click a button that is styled as a searchbox I want to display a menu that is normally hidden with display: none.

I'm okay at Javascript, but right now I'm stuck. The menu opens, and I can click inside the box, but when I click once, the menu closes right away. I want it to stay open until I click outside of the box that is displayed.

Jquery:

```
window.jQuery(function(){
    window.jQuery("#facetuitklap").on("click", function(event){
        window.jQuery("#showfacetuitklap").toggle();
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
    
    var uitklap = window.jQuery("#showfacetuitklap");

    document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        var isClickInsideElement = window.jQuery.contains(uitklap, event.target);
        if (!isClickInsideElement && uitklap.is(":visible")) {
            uitklap.hide();
        }
    });
});
```

CSS

```
div #showfacetuitklap {
    display: none;
    z-index: 200 !important;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: white;
    width: 100%;
}
```

The button that is pressed has an ID of `#facetuitklap`

Comment: I'm probably incorrect, but is this a case of using.

event.preventDefault() in the 'click' function of the navigation tab?

Comment: I was just thinking that.